# Magento - transfer theme to another site

Tags: magento, themes

I've built a site for a customer in Magento (version 1.4), and now need to copy the theme across to a new site for the same customer. Is transferring the theme as simple as copying the relevant folders from 'app' and 'skin' (and then activating in the new Magento installation)?

There are also several extensions I need to install - should I install them before moving the theme so they don't overwrite anything, or will the theme be unaffected by extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the theme you're uploading isn't `base/default` nor `default/default` then it is safe to just copy the files over. No extension should be overwriting in folders that you named.

As for which order to install in, that is personal preference. Personally I would like to know everything functional is working as expected before dressing it up with a theme. Perhaps you would rather tackle the easy task of theming before worrying about extensions you know less about...

Comment: Great - just what I was hoping to hear! Marking this as accepted because it was ever so slightly sooner :P

Comment: @Jonathan - LOL We're getting closer! And you use big words like "orthogonal".

Comment: @What - all good, i knew those 5 seconds would cost me :D @clockworkgeek - yeah, just don't ask me to explain what it means! :)

Comment: If all extensions are working and no further development is required.  How long would it take to apply a Pearl theme to replace a Luma theme?

Answer (score 6):

you should be fine to copy the `app/design/frontend/default/<yourtheme>` and `skin/frontend/default/<yourtheme>` folders across. The extensions should be orthogonal to the themes, assuming that any design changes effected by the extensions have already been incorporated into your theme that you are copying.  So it shouldn't matter what order.